# Oracle SQL - using if clauses to drive variables

Tags: oracle, plsql

Good morning all

I've written the following query:

```
    define AssetVar = "'BA G-ZBJA'"
define DateFromVar = "'12/08/2016 15:00:00'"

define AssetClause = " where Asset = &AssetVar";
define

BEGIN
  IF DateFromVar = ""
    Then define DateFromClause = ""
    ELSE
    define DateFromClause ="and DATETIME >= TO_DATE(&DateFromVar, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')";
  End IF;
End;
define

select * from SCHEDULE &AssetClause &DateFromClause ;

undefine AssetVar DateFromVar AssetClause DateFromClause;
```

The theory is, the end user can set variables and the query will be built based on the variables set, if they set it to nothing, the if statement basically excludes that clause from the final query.

If I provide all variables and remove the IF everything is fine, I think the variables are not being passed into the IF correctly but I'm not sure

Has anyone ever achieved this or know why i's not working?

Answer (score 1):

[`define` is a *client* command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve017.htm), it is not part of the PL/SQL (or indeed SQL) syntax. You can refer substitution variables within an anonymous PL/SQL block but they are evaluated then the block is compiled and you cannot change their values.

You can move all that logic into the query, e.g.:

```
define AssetVar = "BA G-ZBJA"
define DateFromVar = "12/08/2016 15:00:00"

select * from SCHEDULE
where Asset = '&&AssetVar'
and ('&&DateFromVar' is null or DATETIME >= TO_DATE('&&DateFromVar', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
```

With `set verify on` you can see the SQL you end up with:

```
old:select * from SCHEDULE
where Asset = '&&AssetVar'
and ('&&DateFromVar' is null or DATETIME >= TO_DATE('&&DateFromVar', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
new:select * from SCHEDULE
where Asset = 'BA G-ZBJA'
and ('12/08/2016 15:00:00' is null or DATETIME >= TO_DATE('12/08/2016 15:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
```

If you're defining the values then the logic is a bit pointless; it's more likely you're  prompting:

```
accept AssetVar
accept DateFromVar

with schedule(asset, datetime) as (select 'test', sysdate from dual)
select * from SCHEDULE
where Asset = '&&AssetVar'
and ('&&DateFromVar' is null or DATETIME >= TO_DATE('&&DateFromVar', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
```

so if you don't enter a date value the comparison ends up as:

```
...
and ('' is null or DATETIME >= TO_DATE('', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
```

Unfortunately you can't specify a format for an option variable, which would be convenient.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood the point of the question, if the variable is null the entire clause should be excluded

Answer (score 0):

I would use bind variables (`:variable`) instead of substitution variables (`&variable`).

Also, you could use `case` statement in `where` clause instead of `if`.

So the solution would look something like the following:

```
select * from SCHEDULE
where 
Asset = :AssetVar and 
case when DateFromClause = ''  
         then 1
else 
          case when DATETIME >= TO_DATE(:DateFromVar, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
               then 1
          else 
                    0
          end
end   
     = 1
```